# How to use a UIView Subclass as a UICollectionView footer

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I am looking to use a UIView subclass as a collection view footer (UICollectionReusableView). Since the class has already been written as a UIView

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    guard let footerView = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier:"CustomUIView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UICollectionReusableView else { break }
    return footerView
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to cast your CustomUIView as a `UICollectionReusableView` if it doesn't subclass from `UICollectionReusableView`.

You have a couple of options:

- If it works for your needs, you can subclass `UICollectionReusableView` for your CustomUIView class, rather than subclassing `UIView`
- Since `UICollectionReusableView` inherits from `UIView`, you could create a `CustomUIView`, then create a new `UICollectionReusableView` and add the `CustomUIView` you created as a subview